# Creating a JSON object from multidimensional array stored as string

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to generate a JSON object using PHP to be passed to the client using data that is already stored in MySQL database.

The database contains a list of multipolygon coordinates like below in a single text field:

```
[
  [
      [
          [
              104.39209000000005,
              -4.850154
          ],
          [
              108.17138687500005,
              -3.721745195827911
          ],
          [
              112.12646500000005,
              -1.274309
          ],
          [
              103.02978499999995,
              -3.579213
          ]
      ]
  ]
]
```

When I try to generate a JSON object using json_encode I get the following:

```
{
  "coordinates": "[[[[104.39209000000005,-4.850154],[108.17138687500005,-3.721745195827911],[112.12646500000005,-1.274309],[103.02978499999995,-3.579213]]]]"
}
```

And because of the quotes around the coordinates themselves, they are not recognised as JSON object by JavaScript.

I've tried to explode the coordinate string and then put it back together manually but it still needs a lot of hacks to get it working.
Any help in getting this to output as a an actual JSON object in PHP would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to get to this:

```
{
  "coordinates": [
      [
          [
              [
                  104.39209000000005,
                  -4.850154
              ],
              [
                  108.17138687500005,
                  -3.721745195827911
              ],
              [
                  112.12646500000005,
                  -1.274309
              ],
              [
                  103.02978499999995,
                  -3.579213
              ]
          ]
      ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: **show the php code**,how are you getting the data from database, how you are assigning it to a variable?

Comment: Could you simply feed your string through `JSON.parse()` ?

Comment: Or through [`json_decode`](http://us2.php.net/json_decode) on the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty jerry-rigged, but you could do this:

```
$string = json_encode( $database_value ); // same as you're using now
$string = str_replace( '"', '', $string ); // get rid of the quotes

// wrap them back around 'coordinates'
$string = str_replace( 'coordinates', '"coordinates"', $string );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode) before [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode), like this:

```
// This comes from the database, of course
$coords = '[[[[104.39209000000005,-4.850154],[108.17138687500005,-3.721745195827911],[112.12646500000005,-1.274309],[103.02978499999995,-3.579213]]]]';

echo json_encode(array(
    'coordinates' => json_decode($coords)
));
```

This will output nested arrays exactly as you desire:

```
{"coordinates":[[[[104.39209,-4.850154],[108.171386875,-3.7217451958279],[112.126465,-1.274309],[103.029785,-3.579213]]]]}
```